# Spring Authorization Server 0.3.1 CORS issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, springdoc

i created an authorization server using spring-auth-server 0.3.1, and implemented the Authorization code workflow, my issue is that when my front end -springdoc- reaches the last step i get a 401 and this is what's logged into browser console :

```
Access to fetch at 'http://authorization-server:8080/oauth2/token' from origin 'http://client:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

i'm using spring boot 2.6.12 and here is my CORS configuration for authorization server  (also copy pasted it to the client in case ):

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    private final Set<String> allowedOrigins;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfiguration(
            @Value("${spring.security.cors.allowed-origins:*}") List<String> allowedOrigins) {
        this.allowedOrigins = new LinkedHashSet<>(allowedOrigins);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .csrf().disable() // without session cookies we do not need this anymore
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        boolean useAllowedOriginPatterns = allowedOrigins.isEmpty() || allowedOrigins.contains("*");
        if (useAllowedOriginPatterns) {
            configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        } else {
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(new ArrayList<>(allowedOrigins));
        }
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

and here are my security filter chain for the Auth server :

```
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain standardSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
```

Any idea on what i'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by dropping the `CorsConfigurationSource` from filter chain bean and creating a filter instead.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    private final Set<String> allowedOrigins;

    @Autowired
    public SimpleCORSFilter(@Value("${spring.security.cors.allowed-origins:*}") Set<String> allowedOrigins) {
        this.allowedOrigins = allowedOrigins;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String origin = request.getHeader("referer");
        if(origin != null ){
            Optional<String> first = allowedOrigins.stream().filter(origin::startsWith).findFirst();
            first.ifPresent(s -> response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", s));
        }
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your backend and your app are not running on the same address your browser does normally not allow you to call your backend. This is intended to be a security feature.

To allow your browser to call your api add the Access-Control-**** headers to your backend response (when answering from Spring).

please add the below line in your header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

here is an tutorial also, please visit [here on spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Comment: that's what the configuration on the top should have added !  `cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())`

Comment: Hi @Zeus - Did you manage to resolve this issue? I am facing same issue so it will be helpful if you post your fix here

Comment: Hi @Sachin sure, i added my answer, hope that does help u !

Answer (score 0):

Using the new Spring OAuth2Authorization and configuration like this

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
    return http.build();
}
```

Adding a `WebMvcConfigurer` like this will help you with cors:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedMethods("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    }
}
```